# How it is possible to use Photos editing tools inside my iOS 8 app?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photosframework

I'm writing an application that captures an image using `UIImagePickerController`. How is it possible to use iOS 8 Photos app to edit this image?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014408). You can find the WWDC 2014 videos [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) under Introducing the Photos Frameworks.

Comment: I've studied about Photos framework, but i'd like to send my captured image to Photos app, and use Photos editing tools and edit view(tools that was designed by Photos app to edit an image) to edit this image. is it possible?

Comment: Do you require the Image back? Because you can always navigate to the photos app and editing tools can edit the photo. But you can't navigate to the photo nor can you get the image back in the app once you are done. You can use the PhotosUI framework to build the editing tools you require